# How to call MethodInvoke - reflection

Tags: java, reflection

If i have a method which takes a `int[]` as a parameter and i wish to call `method.invoke` on this then do i need to do the following

```
Object[] anArray = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000};
method.invoke(obj, anArray);
```

Is it as simple as that as i seem to be getting errors?

Regards

Comment: Can you post the error as well?

Comment: IllegalArgumentException is being thrown with bad arg list

Comment: post the code that you are using to get 'method'

Comment: why are you declaring an array of integers as an object array and not an int[]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Method.invoke` takes two arguments.  The first is the target, `obj`, which is correct.  The second is an *array* representing zero or more arguments for the actual method you are trying to invoke (many methods have more than one parameter).  Your code should change to:

```
method.invoke(obj, new Object[] { anArray });
```

This way, you're saying "invoke this method with one argument, and that argument is an array.  This is different from saying, "invoke this method with 10 arguments" (one for each element in your array).