# Wrong number of arguments error when invoking a method

Tags: java, reflection, illegalargumentexception

I have class `AClass` and a method `someMethod` that gets an `Object` array as parameter.

```
public class AClass {
    public void someMethod(Object[] parameters) {
    }
}
```

In main, when I try to invoke this method on the the object that I have created and give an object array as a parameter to this method

```
Object[] parameters; // lets say this object array is null
Class class = Class.forName("AClass");
Object anObject = class.newInstance();

Method someMethod = class.getDeclaredMethod("someMethod", parameters.getClass());
someMethod.invoke(anObject, parameters);
```

I get "wrong number of arguments error".
What am i missing?

Comment: I guess this is not your real code. Because it will throw NullPointerException

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call MethodInvoke - reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188870/how-to-call-methodinvoke-reflection)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That will be all right.

```
Object[] parameters = {new Object()}; // lets say this object array is null
Class clas = Class.forName("AClass");
Object anObject = clas.newInstance();

Object[] param = {parameters};

Method someMethod = clas.getDeclaredMethod("someMethod", parameters.getClass());
someMethod.invoke(anObject, param);
```

Be careful about the second parameter of the invoke method. It's `Object[]` itself, and the argument type of your method is `Object[]` too.

Comment: That's confusing; what's `P`? You're passing in an `Object[]` containing an `Object[]` containing an `Object`, nothing null about it.

Comment: It works, but I don't understand why we have to write this line: Object[] param ={parameters};

Comment: beacuse the signature of someMethod is method.invoke(Object obj, Object... args). in fact, someMethod only have one parameter is Object[], so should pass the parameter [Object[]]

Answer (score 19):

To expand a bit on what orien and biaobiaoqi are saying . . .

What's probably confusing you here is that `Method.invoke(Object, Object...)` can usually just take the arguments "inline", so to speak; when the compiler sees something like `someMethod.invoke(someObject, arg1, arg2)`, it implicitly creates an array `new Object[]{arg1, arg2}` and then passes that array to `Method.invoke`. `Method.invoke` then passes the elements of that array as arguments to the method you're invoking. So far, so good.

But when the compiler sees something like `someMethod.invoke(someObject, someArray)`, it assumes that you've already packaged the arguments into an array; so it won't repackage them again. So then `Method.invoke` will try to pass the *elements* of `someArray` as arguments to the method you're invoking, rather than passing `someArray` *itself* as an argument.

(This is always how the `...` notation works; it accepts *either* an array containing elements of the appropriate type, *or* zero or more arguments of the appropriate type.)

So, as orien and biaobiaoqi have said, you need to rewrap your `parameters` into an additional array, `new Object[] {parameters}`, so that `parameters` itself ends up being passed into your method.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Best explanation Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

The `Method.invoke` method takes the object to receive the method call and an array of the arguments to the method. As your method takes one argument, the array given must have a size of `1`.

try creating a new array with size `1`:

```
someMethod.invoke(anObject, new Object[] {parameters});
```

Note that the one value in this array can be `null`. This would simulate `anObject.someMethod(null)`

Answer (score 4):

The parameters to `invoke` is an array of `Object`; your parameters should be an `Object[]` *containing* the `Object[]` you're passing to `someMethod`.

You don't need to create an immediate array to do this, since the `invoke` signature is `invoke(Object, Object...)`, but in your case you're trying to pass in an *empty* array. If you want to pass in null:

```
Object[] parameters = { null };
...
someMethod.invoke(anObject, parameters);
```

Ultimately, however, the other answers are correct: you need to pass in an `Object[]` containing an entry for *each of the methods parameters*.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    someMethod.invoke(anObject, new .java.lang.Object[1][]{parameters});
```

I got by automatically-generating a Reflection API version of your code with dp4j:

```
$ javac -cp dp4j-1.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar -Averbose=true AClass.java
AClass.java:10: Note: 
import com.dp4j.*;

public class AClass {

    public AClass() {
        super();
    }

    public void someMethod(Object[] parameters) {
    }

    @Reflect(all = true)
    public static void main(String... args) throws ... {
        Object[] parameters = null;
        ...
        AClass anObject;
        anObject = (.AClass)aClassConstructor.newInstance();
        java.lang.reflect.Method someMethodWithArrayMethod = null;
        someMethodWithArrayMethod = Class.forName("AClass").getDeclaredMethod("someMethod", .java.lang.Object[].class);
        someMethodWithArrayMethod.setAccessible(true);
        someMethodWithArrayMethod.invoke(anObject, new .java.lang.Object[1][]{parameters});
    }
}
```